# Use two keyboards; One for macros?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I'm wondering if it is possible to actually use another keyboard as a set of "macro keys"?

I have searched a lot online for this, and nowhere can I see that it is possible. Do you know of something similar to that?